# How to create a default error decorator if a view fails in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, python-decorators

I am thinking of an Idea to implement. Usually, I just wrap my view function code in a try-catch block, so if the view fails, I render a default error page with error name.
 I am wondering, can I create a decorator or a similar one-liner code, in which I could do the same(if the code in function crashes, load the error page with error code).
Note I am already using the @login_required decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Daniel is right, just adding links to the right posts. We can use a template processor, pointed out in the following answer, and pass the status code.
[Django raising 404 with a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367374/django-raising-404-with-a-message)

or we can create a new default error page and pass in the error like they did in the following post.
[How to return 404 page intentionally in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465281/how-to-return-404-page-intentionally-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do this. Django captures all errors already. You should simply provide a custom 500.html template at the top level of your templates directory - see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#the-500-server-error-view).

Comment: I cannot show my custom error codes and names, using this method.

Comment: Why do you think you can't?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know to implement this idea. Would you please point me the right way?Any code you would like to show.